# Format date in websql

Tags: web-sql

I am using websql, but problem is, not finding any date functions in websql. I have date stored in the format `Mon Apr 09 2012 15:23:54 GMT+530(India Standard Time)`, and I want the query result in the format `04/09/2012`. Can any body help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSql has a `strftime` function that should do what you need:

```
select strftime('%d-%m-%Y', 'now') formattedDate
```

As noted in the comment below, the data in the column will need to be a valid date time string recognized by SQLite.  Check the [SQLite Date Functions documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for more info.

Comment: Jacob thanks for reply.. specially link given by you is very helpful. But the problem I am facing is, output is correct for 'now', but when I replace with column of the table, which has date, result is blank.

Comment: "strftime" function worked when I changed the format. I used iso Utc DateTime format instead of default format and it worked. Thanks Jocob.