# How to get current date and time in websql?

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I wanted to know how to get current date and time and what datatype should i use to store it in websql, sorry for being such a noob...

Comment: Probbaly this link helps
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104893/format-date-in-websql][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104893/format-date-in-websql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `Date` object and store the numeric value of the date as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC (negative for prior times).

```
var today = new Date();
today.getTime();        // returns "1337217238392"
```

Storing the milliseconds will allow you to read and parse however you like later. Its worth mentioning to check out [date.js](http://datejs.com) and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com)

Comment: is there anyway where in.. while i write insert statement i can get date object from websql instead from javascript ?

Comment: i'm not familiar with websql... i'm sure there is.